# menu link to custom post_type?

Tags: custom-post-types, menus, permalinks

is there a way to add a custom post_type (directors) link to a menu? I can add the individual director posts but not the link to all of them.

I'd like to avoid using custom links as this will be used in several sites and not always at the root. (so making a default /directors/ wont always work). PLus i'd like it to behave like normal menu links when active etc.

best, Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok - got this working with a walker in the end;
(added a custom directors link to the menu)

```
class Director_nav_links extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item ) );
        $class_names = ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

        $output .= $indent . '<li id="menu-item-'. $item->ID . '"' . $value . $class_names .'> ';

        $attributes = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target ) ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr( $item->xfn ) .'"' : '';

        //  automatically add wp folder to url
        if(strtolower($item->post_title) == 'directors' ) $item->url = get_post_type_archive_link('directors');

        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url ) ? ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"' : '';
        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '<br /><span class="sub">' . $item->description . '</span>';
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using a Walker? Aren't you adding only one link to the post type archive?

Comment: want to make sure the custom link works across multiple sites whether its using the root directory or a custom folder.